# Show that $|H \cap A_4|=|H\cap (12)A_4|$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups

> Let $H\le S_4$ be a subgroup such that $H \not\subset A_4$. Show that $|H \cap A_4|=|H\cap (12)A_4|$. I would like to have a hint for the cinstruction of the bijection. Here is my attempt:

Each element of $A_4$ is of sign $1$. If we look at $(12)A_4$, then clearly sign of it's elements is $-1$ and $|(12)A_4|=12$. We observe first that $A_4\cap (12)A_4=\emptyset$ and that $S_4=A_4\sqcup (12)A_4$.

Then, as $H\not\subset A_4$, clearly $H\cap(12)A_4 \neq \emptyset$ (probably $H\subseteq (12)A_4 (?) )$.

Now, I have to show that $|H\cap A_4|=|H\cap (12)A_4|$. To show it's order equality, I have to find a bijection between $H\cap A_4$ and $H\cap (12)A_4$ (or injection in 2 different "directions" and apply Shroeder Bernstein's theorem). But, I dont't really see how to define it properly as $H\cap A_4 =\emptyset$ or it has an intersection. If someone could give a **hint**, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Basically, you want to show that $H$ has an equal number of odd and even permutations. What can you say about $\sum_{\sigma\in H} \text{sgn}(\sigma)$, where $\text{sgn}$ is the sign of the permutation?

Comment: Also $\text{Id.}\notin(12)A_4$ so $H\subseteq (12)A_4$ can't be true.

Comment: @lc2r43 I think you can conclude that the sum is equal to $0$, but I don't really see how to develop... I don't really understand why $H\cap A_4$ is certainly not an empty set

Comment: What are the even and odd parts of that sum?

Comment: @lc2r43 Odd are in $H\cap (12)A_4$ and even are in $H\cap A_4$. But if we decompose the sum like this, we have to have an hypothesis that $H=H\cap(12)A_4\sqcup H\cap A_4$, no?

Comment: H inherits the decomposition into odd and even permutations from $S_4$. A permutation can't be both even and odd at the same time. $H\cap A_4$ can't be empty because of the identity element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_4$ is a normal subgroup of $S_4$ with index 2. Proof this for $A_4\cap H\subseteq H$.